# Parse.Query don't work if used in a different file than main.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

From my cloud/main.js file I have this query:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('name', function (req, res) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var measure = Parse.Object.extend("Measurement");
    var query = new Parse.Query(measure);
    query.find().then((res) => console.log(res.length)) // return 48 records 
});
```

If a I make the same query on file dataAnalysis.js that is required in the main.js.
In the main.js:

```
 var Compute = require('./dataAnalysis');
 Parse.Cloud.define('name', function (req, res) {
     Compute.test();
 });
```

In the dataAnalysis.js:

```
var Compute = {
    test: ()=>{
        Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
        var measure = Parse.Object.extend("Measurement");
        var query = new Parse.Query(measure);
        query.find().then((res) => console.log(res.length)) // returns 0 record
}
module.exports = Compute;
```

But this query return always 0 results.

I also tried to include:

```
var Parse = require('parse/node').Parse;
Parse.initialize('xxxxx', null, 'xxxxx');
Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse';
```

But it's the same, always 0 results.

I'm doing something wrong?

Additional info:

```
"parse": "1.9.2", 
"parse-server": "^2.2.25-beta.1" // Also tried 2.2.23
node version: v6.9.1
```

Comment: what is the value of the ACL prop on the "Measurement"  class?? There may exist Measurement.objects to which your query user has no read privs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually there is no ACL for the class. Each record have an ACL so that only the user that created it is able to read it. Btw I'm using the master key here so the ACL should not be a problem...

Comment: hmm -  maybe u should recheck that the exported definitions that delegate to the dataAnalysis.js are all good. I also use that exported/require delegated paths on parse-server local : 1337 and it is fine.

Comment: the `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` **doesnt work on parse-server**, you have to build your query differently [like this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/37), also before you say it doesnt work in your dataAnalysis file test the function in main.js

Comment: @MazelTov Actually `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` works. If I remove it I don't have any results also in the `main.js` file. Btw I also tried with mainQuery.find({useMasterKey: true}) but nothing change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I copied and pasted the full function on the dataAnalysis.js file and call it from my main.js file and it works. As the snippet here was just an extract of a more bigger function the problem is probably somewhere else.